# golang comma separated expression

Tags: go

In go docs there is a shuffle example ([link](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/))

I've added some output to it as follows:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    words := strings.Fields("ink runs from the corners of my mouth")
    fmt.Println(words)
    rand.Shuffle(len(words), func(i, j int) {
        fmt.Println("Before:", i, j, words[i])
        words[i], words[j] = words[j], words[i]
        fmt.Println("After:", i, j, words[i])

    })
    fmt.Println(words)
}
```

What I would like to understand is the line that has:

```
words[i], words[j] = words[j], words[i]
```

And specifically why the output before and after that statement is different. How is this evaluated? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Assignments](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments)
>
> A tuple assignment assigns the individual elements of a multi-valued
>   operation to a list of variables. There are two forms. In the first,
>   the right hand operand is a single multi-valued expression such as a
>   function call, a channel or map operation, or a type assertion. The
>   number of operands on the left hand side must match the number of
>   values. For instance, if f is a function returning two values,
>
> ```
> x, y = f()
> ```
>
> assigns the first value to x and the second to y. In the second form,
>   the number of operands on the left must equal the number of
>   expressions on the right, each of which must be single-valued, and the
>   nth expression on the right is assigned to the nth operand on the
>   left:
>
> ```
> one, two, three = '一', '二', '三'
> ```

---

`words[i], words[j] = words[j], words[i]` is the second form of a Go tuple assignment. The values of `words[i]`and `words[j]` are swapped.

`words[i], words[j] = words[j], words[i]`

becomes:

```
// on the left
tj := words[j]
ti := words[i]
// on the right
words[i] = tj
words[j] = ti
```

simplify:

```
t := words[i]
words[i] = words[j]
words[j] = t
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I feel a bit silly since I was reading it as a single expression (words[i]) (words[j] = words[j]) and then (words[i]) again. Instead of the proper (words[i], words[j]) = (words[j], words[i]). I suppose my internal parser was glitching - but thanks again.